# How can I stop the popup "pcdrsysinfosoftware.p5x - Entry Point Not Found"?

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop

I'm getting this popup sometimes on my Dell Windows 8 (upgraded from Windows 7) Laptop. I want to know why I get this and how to stop it.

> #### pcdrsysinfosoftware.p5x - Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point SymSetScopeFromInlineContext could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgeng.dll

[image: Screenshot of popup]

Comment: install a newer Version of the `Debugging Tools for Windows`

Answer (score 4):

So you keep getting:

> The procedure entry point SymSetScopeFromInLineContext could not be located in the dynamic link library
>
> c:\windows\system32\dbgeng.dll

dbgeng.dll is a Windows system file. If it has been corrupted, you can repair it like this:

1. open an administrative command prompt
2. type this command (w/o quotes) "sfc /scannow"

If **sfc /scannnow** doesn't works, I suggest trying the new advanced boot options in Windows 8:

1. Hold Win + R (Windows Key and R at the same time)
2. TYPE:  `shutdown /r /o /f /t 00`

The computer will reboot, Select:

- TROUBLESHOOT
- ADVANCED OPTIONS
- COMMAND PROMPT

At the command prompt, type:

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d:\ /offwindir=d:\windows
```

Source: http://www.pcdoctor-community.com/forum/index.php?topic=687.0